# Magento: Create an invoice with invoice number = order number?

Tags: magento-1.4, invoice

I am using this code to create an invoice in Magento:

```
$invoiceId = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice_api')->create($order->getIncrementId(), array());
```

This automatically assigns a number (increment_id) to the invoice, for example 100016050. I want to create an invoice where **the increment_id of the invoice = the increment_id of the order**.

How can that be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This would require coding a complete custom module, so I'll just explain some basics.

In Magento, entities like `order`, `invoice`, `creditmemo` and `shipping` each have its own and independant number group per `store_id`.

These number groups can be defined in the table `eav_entity_store`:

```
entity_store_id  entity_type_id  store_id  increment_prefix  increment_last_id
              1               5         1                 1          100000000
              2               6         1                 2          200000000
              3               7         1                 3          300000000
              4               8         1                 4          400000000
```

To know which entity_type_id refers to which entity, check your `eav_entity_type` table:

```
entity_type_id  entity_type_code  entity_model
             5  order             sales/order
             6  invoice           sales/order_invoice
             7  creditmemo        sales/order_creditmemo
             8  shipment          sales/order_shipment
```

Note that your `entity_type_id`'s may (or may not) vary from that.

Magento usually increments each of this entities by one, see `eav_entity_type.increment_per_store`.

This happens the time such entity is created. But, the creation of an `order` doesn't always mean, that an `invoice` for it will be created, too. For example the user could cancel the payment while order placing, or the payment will not be authorized by the payment provider, so no `invoice` would be created.

This may lead to gaps, e.g. `order` already at `100000005`, while `invoice` still at `200000002`.

Your code would need to manage this gap in a way that keeps `order` and `invoice` in sync.

To do this, you could create an observer for the `sales_order_invoice_save_before` event, for example.

`app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/etc/config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </mymodule>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_invoice_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <myobserver>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                        <method>salesOrderInvoiceSaveBefore</method>
                    </myobserver>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_invoice_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/Model/Observer.php`:

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer
{

    /**
     * Hook to observe `sales_order_invoice_save_before` event
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $oObserver
     */

    public function salesOrderInvoiceSaveBefore($oObserver)
    {
        $oInvoice = $oObserver->getInvoice();
    }

}
```

Magento passes the `invoice` object to this observer, before the `invoice` object is saved. This would allow you to retrieve the related `order` object (and therefore the `order`'s `increment_id`) using this `invoice` object.

Having retrieved the `order.increment_id` you could search the `invoice`s to find out whether or not an `invoice` with that `order.increment_id` already exists.

If it doesn't exist yet, you can assign the value of `order.increment_id` to `invoice.increment_id` before leaving the observer and are done.

Please note, that these are only the basics. There are some more pitfalls to it.

For example, multiple and/or duplicate invoices per order cases are not handled yet.

For example, in some countries the fiscal/tax authorities require invoice numbers to be continuously increasing. It must be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, but `1, 2, 3, 4 is missing, 5` is not acceptable. Using the technique above, such gaps can still happen, because of payment cancellations by the user, etc.

However, this should get you on the right track.